# PANIC: unprotected error in call to Lua API (wificonfig.lua:33: address in use)

Tags: lua, esp8266, httpserver, nodemcu, panic

I'm trying to create a local http server on ESP8266 with lua using NodeMCU custom build by frightanic.com.

When i create a local http server along with a connection that is already listening on port 80 and fetching data from my server site, it is giving me PANIC error.

Here's my code :

```
wifi.setmode(wifi.STATION)
wifi.sta.config("SSID","password")
wifi.sta.connect()

tmr.alarm(1,10000, 1, function()
    if (wifi.sta.getip() == nil) then
        print("IP unavaiable, Waiting...")
    else
        foo()
        local_server()
    end
end)


function foo()
        conn = nil
        conn=net.createConnection(net.TCP,0)
        conn:on("receive", function(conn, payload)
            print("payload : "..#payload);
        end)
        conn:connect(80,"server.co.in")
        conn:on("connection", function(conn, payload)
            conn:send("GET /mypage?id=deadbeef HTTP/1.0\r\nHost: server.co.in\r\nConnection: keep-alive\r\nAccept: */*\r\n\r\n") end)

        conn:on("sent",function(conn)
                print("Closing server connection")
                conn:close()
            end)
end

function local_server()
    srv=net.createServer(net.TCP)
    srv:listen(80,function(conn)
        conn:on("receive", function(client,request)
            local buf = "Hello world";
            client:send('HTTP/1.0\n\n')
            client:send('<!DOCTYPE HTML>\n')
            client:send('<html>\n')
            client:send('<head><meta  content="text/html; charset=utf-8">\n')
            client:send('<title>Local server</title></head>\n')
            client:send('<style>body{ background-color: #cccccc; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, Sans-Serif; Color: #000088; }</style>\n";')
            client:send(buf);

            conn:on("sent",function(conn)
                srv:close() -- Even tried with client:close()
            end)
        end)
    end)

end
```

Is it not possible to do this ? If yes, than how can i do it ?

If i create server once inside timer, than it doesn't create any local server ie. i'm not able to open my local server 192.168.x.y.

Here's my modified code :

```
wifi.setmode(wifi.STATION)
wifi.sta.config("SSID","password")
wifi.sta.connect()

tmr.alarm(1,10000, 1, function()
    if (wifi.sta.getip() == nil) then
        print("IP unavaiable, Waiting...")
    else
        print("Creating a server");
        srv=net.createServer(net.TCP,0)
        srv:listen(80,function(conn) 
        end)
        tmr.stop(1)
        tmr.alarm(1,10000, 1, function() 
              foo()
              local_server()
        end)
    end
end)


function foo()
        conn = nil
        conn=net.createConnection(net.TCP,0)
        conn:on("receive", function(conn, payload)
            print("payload : "..#payload);
        end)
        conn:connect(80,"server.co.in")
        conn:on("connection", function(conn, payload)
            conn:send("GET /mypage?id=deadbeef HTTP/1.0\r\nHost: server.co.in\r\nConnection: keep-alive\r\nAccept: */*\r\n\r\n") end)

        conn:on("sent",function(conn)
                print("Closing server connection")
                conn:close()
            end)
end

function local_server()
        conn:on("receive", function(client,request)
            local buf = "Hello world";
            client:send('HTTP/1.0\n\n')
            client:send('<!DOCTYPE HTML>\n')
            client:send('<html>\n')
            client:send('<head><meta  content="text/html; charset=utf-8">\n')
            client:send('<title>Local server</title></head>\n')
            client:send('<style>body{ background-color: #cccccc; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, Sans-Serif; Color: #000088; }</style>\n";')
            client:send(buf);

            conn:on("sent",function(conn)
                srv:close() -- Even tried with client:close()
            end)
        end)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
>         client:send('HTTP/1.0\n\n')
> ```

This is not a valid HTTP response. At minimum a response serving a HTML page should look like this

```
 HTTP/1.0 200 ok\r\n
 Content-type: text/html\r\n
 \r\n
 here comes the HTML body
```

But this is probably not the reason for the panic since it complains about address in use. I don't know anything about the OS running on ESP8266 but usually this error means that there is already a socket bound to this address and port and that you cannot have another one at the same location. Thus if there is already a web server running at this system then you cannot start another web server at the same address.

Such error can also happen if you've started the server once successfully, failed to communicate (due to improper HTTP response by your server) and then try to restart the server again: it will take some time before you can reuse the same socket once a connection was established to this socket so you might need to wait some minutes before starting a server again (or just reboot the system).

Taking a closer look at your code one can see that the server is started from inside a timer:

```
tmr.alarm(1,10000, 1, function()
...
        local_server()
```

From a quick look at [the documentation of tmr](https://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/master/en/modules/tmr/#tmralarm) it looks like you are calling the timer with `tmr.ALARM_AUTO` so that it will repeat again and again. This means that the timer will be repeated after you've setup the server already and thus try to setup the server again - on the same port. This causes the error of address in use.

Comment: I initially used  HTTP/1.0 200 ok itself but when it didn't work than was trying with HTTP/1.0 because i don't have much knowledge of this stuff.

The address which the error refers to is the IP address of my WiFi module (working as a station connected to an access point) or is it some other address ?

As you can see in my code i have opened a client connection on port 80 to some server which i then close.conn:connect(80,"server.co.in")

Comment: I even tried listening to other port say 9999 but i was getting the same error.

Comment: The error message refers to is local to your WiFi module. I would suggest that you simplify your code first, i.e. implement only a server and nothing else.

Comment: foo() and local_server() works fine if called separately but if both of them are called inside a single lua script than this error occurs, probably because it was already listening on port 80 for local http server and if i try to make a connection on same port than it gives PANIC error.

But i don't know how to correct it.

Comment: @aditgupta100: see updated answer: from my understanding of your code you are setting up the server multiple times because you use a repeating timer.

Comment: even i was guessing the same but i don't know how to rescue the problem. Now i modified the code (see updated code in question), creating server only once... but now i couldn't open local server 192.168.x.y ... However there's no error

Comment: @aditgupta100: I have the feeling that you are just fiddling with the code without really understanding what you do. It makes no sense to setup the receive handler on the server again and again. Apart from that: the original problem you had (address in use) is explained and solved. Now you have a different problem so please ask a new question. This is not a discussion site and modifying the question to ask a different thing or asking new things inside a comment is not how it works here.